# My ios app is not registered for universal link

Tags: cordova, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

My app passed the Apple validator tool. I have a valid AASA file. I also checked both `Entitlements-Debug.plist` and `Entitlements-Release.plist` are correct, as below:

**apple-app-site-association**

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "MY_TEAM_ID.bunldeID",
        "paths": [
          "*",
          "/"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Entitlements-Debug.plist**

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:*.mysite.io</string>
        <string>applinks:*.mysite.com</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then I build with Xcode for both simulator and real device but when I did `long press` a link (I prepared a few ones in Gmail), it didn't show my app as an option in the popup menu of ios. This means my app is not registered universal links.

I also checked nginx log but there was not any requests to `https://abc.mysite.io/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`. From Apple's documentation, it should download this file every time I uninstall then reinstall the app. I'm getting stuck on this.

I would appreciate any ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those are getting the same issue: I changed the wildcard links to specific links then it worked.